# How to create custom invoice fields in Xero?

Tags: accounting, xero-api

Is anyone knows how to create customized fileds in our Xero invoices? We are a tour company and we need to add the following fields.

Date of Sale, Booking ID, Guest Name, Tour Name, Children, Adults etc.

Our tour booking system is generating and sending the invoices automatically. I am using xero API to create the same invoice in Xero.

So I have to create an invoice using the API which would look like below

[image]
But I have only the following fields in Xero.

Description, Quantity, Unit price, Amount.

Because, I don't have fields such as booking id, guest name, tour name, I have to put all this information in the description so it looks like below when invoice is recorded in Xero.

[image]

The second issue is that the discount field is never shown on the xero invoice. We can see it inside the Xero when viewing an invoice it says **Subtotal (includes a discount of 44.55)** but this is never been shown on the actual invoice.

Also Every time I have to create a new line / item using the API if I have children attending to a tour. Please see the screenshot below.

[image]

This is a big issue for us as the invoice that is sent to a guest and the invoice that has been recorded in xero looks different. See the actual invoice below.

[image]

It will make my day if I could use the above mentioned fields in our invoices. Most importantly I should able to send the information for each field using the Xero API.

I am shocked that a famous online account system like Xero doesn't allow us to have this flexibility. Every business has their own unique data and for them to create their own fields means that a lot of the feature requests such as Order ID, Adults, Children etc. should be self defined. I would appreciate any comment and I would appreciate if you can tell me how to reach to Xero developer team as there is no phone number or email address on the offical xero website.

Comment: This question is a perfect fit for the Accounting site (currently a proposal in Area 51: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/113560/accounting?referrer=FNOG9_mXNYnhlAdnl9FE8w2 )

Answer (score 3):

Xero simply does not provide this functionality in either their API or the native product. This should have been discovered during the due diligence phase when deciding what accounting package to use.